# How to check if crosswalk webview?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I'm building a responsive website. When the user enters to the website through a browser such as Chrome, IE or Firefox, I want to show the links of play store and apple store. But if the user enters to the website through crosswal webview, I want to open the application.

It's possible? or it is bad idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't say if it is a good or bad idea, but you can check for CrossWalk WebView using client's user agent:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('crosswalk') > -1) {
    // this is crosswalk view
} else {
    // this is NOT crosswalk view
}
```

Had the [same question myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36945869/52317) and saw yours. Found an answer and thought I'ld share it here as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response!!