# How to check for Crosswalk WebView user agent?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, user-agent, hybrid-mobile-app, crosswalk

I need to check if a mobile user is accessing the website through a Crosswalk WebView and enable/disable some niceties.

How can I check if user is accessing using Crosswalk WebView? What is the user string for Crosswalk WebView?

Answer (score 2):

Found the correct [user agent string](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-user-agent) for crosswalk webview on GitHub:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('crosswalk') > -1) {
    // this is crosswalk view
} else {
    // this is NOT crosswalk view
}
```